# iOS Location - Significant Location Change in iOS 8/9 can start standard location service?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, location, background-service

Many questions concerning iOS Location tracking have been asked on here, but recently Apple has updated much of their functionality and so many of the answers are obsolete, my question is specifically targeting iOS 8 and 9.

I am interested in creating a location tracking application which will accurately track the user even when the app is closed.  To do this, apple states:

> If you leave the significant-change location service running and your
> iOS app is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service
> automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives. At
> wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a
> small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location
> services and process the location data.

So my understanding is, if you have all of the necesarry permission and plist keys present, the OS will wake up your app and allow you to do something for 10 seconds, or if it needs more time it can:

> If an iOS app needs more time to process the location data, it can
> request more background execution time using the
> beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: method of the
> UIApplication class.

Now, this says that if my app needs more time to process the location data, it may start a background task (with an expirationHandler) to handle that.  When reading about background tasks, I read that background tasks can run for a **maximum of 10 minutes**

So my overall question is, **when my app gets woken up when a *significant location change* has occurred, is it possible to start the *standard location service* and have it run in the background indefinitely?  Is it possible to start another background task before the first one expires?**

**EDIT:**
From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) it says:

> because it wakes the system and your app at least every 15 minutes,
> even if no location changes have occurred, and it runs continuously
> until you stop it

So my idea is, if the user starts their phone from nothing and never opens the app, after at most 15 minutes (even if they are standing still), the OS will fire my app, in which case I could start a background process that I can start the GPS tracking in, and thus getting **accurate GPS location**.  Would this logic work with the OS?

Comment: did you managed to find an answer by yourself? I am having the same problem understanding if this can be done or not...

Comment: The simple answer is Yes, this can be done as I had imagined.  Basically you will enable Significant Location Change and Standard Location whenever you app starts up (can be done from AppDelegate) that way if the user terminates the app, if a significant location change has occurred (about 500 meters or so) it will start up and also start the standard tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that significant location changes cannot be used for 
"accurately track" the user.
Significant means 1000m, since it is cell tower based, and not GPS based.
So your app is woke up when the user moves into the next GSM cell.
This is not acurate enough for acurate tracking.

finally this means you cannot acuratley track when the app is closed, this works only in running app or background running up.

> "When reading about background tasks, I read that background tasks can
>   run for a maximum of 10 minutes"

No, thats not true. My app runs in background and records GPS locations until the battery is drained (8h+). (It does not use the significant location mode)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does your app get woken up if it is closed though?  The Apple documentation also says that Significant Location Change will also wake up the app after 15minutes regardless of location change.  So i'm saying, when the app is woken up, I will fire of background processes that will keep it running indefinitely.  Is that possible?

Comment: No, since I do not use Signif. location service, it is not woken up.

Comment: Further there is absolutely no need to track a user when he closes the applicastion. The only app that should do this is in case of stolen device, and for that apple has one pre-installed.

Comment: The app that I'm creating is to track workers while they're in the field, which is an honest app since they are aware that it is running.  I'm attempting to create the app such that they can't simply close it down and it won't run anymore, but that it'll automatically reopen.  So from what I'm seeing it's not possible for iOS?

Comment: No, for good reasons that is not possible. The owner of the mobile phone, decides which app is running. You could send them an SMS when the app is down (asuming the workers work in a region where the APP can send a message to your server. in reguilary intervalls (alive message)

Comment: @AlexWien hey, I need to make an app which will be collecting GPS data even if the app goes into ***background***. And I'm very new with this _location services_. Can you guide me something that'll lead me to implement this functionality??